# WordPress wp_revisions_to_keep filter doesn't work if I set post id

Tags: wordpress, add-filter

I want to limit number of revisions to 2 for posts that weren't modified for 30 days.

I have below function:

```
add_filter( 'wp_revisions_to_keep', 'limit_revisions', 10, 2 );

function limit_revisions( $num, $post ) {

    $num = 2;
    if ( get_the_modified_time( 'U', $post->ID ) + MONTH_IN_SECONDS >= current_time( 'U' ) ) {
        $num = -1;
    }

    return $num;
}
```

It returns a proper `$num` value but it doesn't delete old revisions if I update an old post.

It works as expected if I remove `$post->ID` from `get_the_modified_time` function, but I don't understand why. What is wrong in setting id as a parameter of this function that it makes the filter not working?

Comment: This may happen because you need to pass the `id` as a variable. That said, `get_the_modified_time()` accepts the post object, so try `get_the_modified_time( 'U', $post )` instead

Comment: This function accepts post object or post id (int), so why it doesn't work with id?

Comment: It probably does work with ID, but you might need to assign it to a variable first: e.g. `$post_id = $post->ID; get_the_modified_time( 'U', $post_id  );`

Comment: This way it also doesn't work.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_revisions_to_keep/
Does `limit_revisions` function make sense to anyone? Why passing $num if you hardcoding it in?

Comment: Ah, @Fresz unlocked the reason `$post` doesn't work. `wp_revisions_to_keep()` accepts one argument: `post`. You can pass the `$num` but it needs to be second, but since you are hardcoding, there is no reason to pass it at all. `add_filter( 'wp_revisions_to_keep', 'limit_revisions');` And `function limit_revisions( $post ) {...}`

Answer (score 1):

As user Fresz points out, you don't need to pass `$num` to your `limit_revisions` function.

If you look at the documentation to `wp_revisions_to_keep`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_revisions_to_keep/ you'll notice that it takes one argument: `post`.

In your current setup, you have `limit_revisions( $num, $post )` - that means `$num` is actually the `post` - since you are passing it first.

You can refactor your code to this:

```
add_filter( 'wp_revisions_to_keep', 'limit_revisions');
// Pass only post
function limit_revisions( $post ) {
    $num = 2;

    if ( get_the_modified_time( 'U', $post->ID ) + MONTH_IN_SECONDS >= current_time( 'U' ) ) {
        $num = -1;
    }

    return $num;
}
```

Comment: woop woop :) :)

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure if it's a good solution. It works but I'm getting know "Notice: Trying to get property 'ID' of non-object" and `var_dump($post)` gives int(-1).

Comment: Where are you `var_dump`-ing this?

Comment: Try `error_log(print_r($post))` and see what it returns.

Comment: Try adding `global $post;` above `$num = 2;`

Comment: This way it doesn't remove old revisions. Also, I realized that when I added `global $post` and Classic Editor plugin is active, `var_dump($post->ID)` returns id as a string, however when I'm in Gutenberg, it returns it as an int. And no matter if `global $post` and `$post->ID` is added or not, in gutenberg the function is called twice and I can't save a post because I have an error that response is not a valid JSON response. Any ideas why it all works like this?